# Context of "何様のつもりか"

Tags: translation, meaning, set-phrases

I came across someone referring to the phrase "何様のつもりか" in the middle of an English-language discussion:

> if I were [person X], I would be shouting "何様のつもりか" (although I am not, and so I can't)

[Weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%95%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A) gives a translation of "Who the hell do ... think ... are?"

jisho.org says that [何様](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%95%E6%A7%98) means a person of importance, often used sarcastically, and [つもり](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82%E3%82%8A) has meanings of intention, plan, conviction, or belief.

I guess the translation of phrase makes sense based on its component words (the author is accusing someone of taking over person X's project), but is there any other context I should know about this phrase?

Comment: Without more context, I would take it to mean "who do you think you are?!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a strong phrase. It is often used to start accusing or fighting.

"You are so rude." would be close.